# How to create (probably)nested query?

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have 3 entities Patient with id , Workers with id , profession and PatientDeclaration with patient_id(fk) and workers_id(fk). I want to get workers_id from PatientDeclaration when I have patient_id and profession. Something like that,

```
'SELECT c FROM SurgeryPatientBundle:PatientDeclaration c WHERE c.patient = ?1 AND c.patient =(SELECT w  FROM SurgeryWorkersBundle:Workers  WHERE p.profession = ?2)'
```

I suposse that I have create nested query? 
edit
Solved I make diffrent query

```
SELECT w.id FROM SurgeryWorkersBundle:Workers w JOIN w.patientdeclaration p WHERE w.profession = ?1 AND p.patient = ?2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery

```
SELECT 
    c 
FROM 
    SurgeryPatientBundle:PatientDeclaration c 
JOIN
    c.patient p
WHERE 
    p = ?1 
    AND 
    p.id IN (SELECT w.id FROM SurgeryWorkersBundle:Workers  WHERE p.profession = ?2)
```